# parallax scrolling in android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a layout which i want to apply parallax scrolling on. My layout is as follows :

[image]

And the relevant XML is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/top_control_bar"
        android:background="@drawable/container_dropshadow">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/logo_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/organiser_logo"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_control_bar">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top_control_bar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/container_dropshadow"
            android:id="@+id/explanation_wrapper">
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/no_event_header"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:id="@+id/explanation_header"
                android:padding="8dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/no_event_text_1st_paragraph"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/explanation_1st_paragraph"
                android:paddingTop="8dip"
                android:paddingRight="20dip"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/album_active_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:background="@drawable/container_dropshadow"
            android:layout_below="@+id/explanation_wrapper" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I need to get the middle layer to be scrolled over the bottom layer. And when there is no space left in the top (middle layer is completely scrolled over bottom layer), then i need the top layer to be scrolled over the Middle layer.

How would i achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself after experimenting with the XML layout. The relevant XML is this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
  android:background="#ffffff"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff00ff"
        android:padding="15dip"
        android:text="Hello ParallaxScrollView 1 !"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>

     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- This Linearlayout is used as padding but 60dip is fixed so that needs to be calculated dynamically-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:baselineAligned="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>

             <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#dddddd"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#ff0000"
                        android:padding="15dip"
                        android:text="Hello ParallaxScrollView 1 !" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#ff0000"
                        android:padding="15dip"
                        android:text="Hello ParallaxScrollView 1 !" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#ff0000"
                        android:padding="15dip"
                        android:text="Hello ParallaxScrollView 1 !" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#ff0000"
                        android:padding="15dip"
                        android:text="Hello ParallaxScrollView 1 !" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#ff0000"
                        android:padding="15dip"
                        android:text="Hello ParallaxScrollView 1 !" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#ff0000"
                        android:padding="15dip"
                        android:text="Hello ParallaxScrollView 1 !" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#ff0000"
                        android:padding="15dip"
                        android:text="Hello ParallaxScrollView 1 !" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#ff0000"
                        android:padding="15dip"
                        android:text="Hello ParallaxScrollView 1 !" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#ff0000"
                        android:padding="15dip"
                        android:text="Hello ParallaxScrollView 1 !" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>   

                </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

     </ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```